# Почему смогла пройти сериализация, если нет атрибута [Serializable]?

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Описан несложный класс в .dll с несколькими простыми свойствами `int`/`string`.

**Класс не помечен как `[Serializable]`.**

В консольном приложении проведена стандартная сериализация массива этого класса:

```
XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tiles[]));
try
{
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
  sr.Serialize(sw, arr);
  sw.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.Write(e);
}
```

Никаких ошибок не ловится, десериализация тоже проходит успешно. Как так? Кто-то по умолчанию ставит этот атрибут?

---

Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Атрибут `[Serializable]` относится лишь к бинарной сериализации, а у вас XML-сериализация. Попробуйте бинарную сериализацию, она вот не должна работать.

Comment: (Перенёс в ответ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите.

В .NET есть [несколько различных видов сериализации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/serialization-guidelines).

Атрибут `[Serializable]` относится лишь к бинарной (`BinaryFormatter` и `SoapFormatter`) сериализации. Вот такая тестовая программа использует [`BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
class Tiles
{
    public int X;
    public string Y { get; set; }
    double Z;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new Tiles[] { new Tiles { X = 1, Y = "2" } };

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Она производит исключение, и выводит ожидаемое сообщение:

> Type 'Test.Tiles' in Assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

То же самое происходит при использовании [`SoapFormatter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2).

---

В вашем примере используется не бинарная, а XML-сериализация. Для того, чтобы эта сериализация (а также, например, JSON-сериализация с библиотекой JSON.NET) работала, атрибут `[Serializable]` не нужен.